# How to force DIV to appear inline and in the same offset from right in my HTML template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

in my HTML template . I am having a list of categories and subcategories .
Where each category can have from 0 to n subcategories .

I display those  in 2 for loops one inside other .

```
Category 1
  Subcategory 1
  Subcategory 2
Category 2
  Subcategory 3
  Subcategory 4
  Subcategory 5
```

I also have  drop down menu  that will be specific for each category and subcategory.

So my problem that no meter what I do I can not force my drop down NOT to start from next line .
This is how it looks like now:

```
Category 1                 
menu
Subcategory 1       
menu
Subcategory 2       
menu
Category 2                
menu
Subcategory 3       
menu
Subcategory 4       
menu
Subcategory 5       
menu
Category 3                 
menu
```

See Screen shot:
[image: This is how my screen looks like now]
My goal is to have  drop downs  in the same line as category or subcategory as well to have them aligned under each other.(All the Category drop downs will be on the most right side when all the subcategory will be on the most right but with some fixed offset.

```
Category 1                 menu
  Subcategory 1       menu
  Subcategory 2       menu
Category 2                 menu
  Subcategory 3       menu
  Subcategory 4       menu
  Subcategory 5       menu
Category 3                 menu
```

This is my html:

```
          <div class="well">
          <div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; height: 500px;">
              <ul class="nav nav-list">


                {% for category in page_category %}
                    {# Each "category" is a Category model object. #}


              <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">Category:{{ category.name }}

                   <!--Menu dropdown Div-->
                      <div class="dropdown">
                            <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">Options</span>
                              <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                              <li> <a href="{% url 'subcategory_new' pk=category.id %}">Create subcategory</a></li>
                              <li> <a href="{% url 'subcategory_new' pk=category.id %}">Delete</a></li>
                              <li> <a href="{% url 'subcategory_new' pk=category.id %}">Edit</a></li>
                            </ul>
                      </div>

                  </label>

                <ul class="nav nav-list tree">

                        <lh>Sub Category</lh>

                        {% for field in category.subcategory_set.all %}

                                 <li>#{{ field.id }} {{ field.name }} - {{ field.description }} {{ field.keywords }}

                                   <div class="dropdown">
                                        <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">Options</span>
                                          <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </a>

                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                                          <li><a href="{% url 'subcategory_new' pk=category.id %}">Create subcategory</a></li>

                                          <li><a href="{% url 'company_new' %}">Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>



                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                    </li> <li class="divider"></li><!--category li closing-->


          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Script  I use to toggle visibility

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label.tree-toggler').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
    });
});
```

BTW any other design idea are welcome. I use Django Framework and bootstrap and JQuery .

Comment: Could you please provide an example? A fiddle or something where we can see what you mean?

Comment: I added a screen shot to my Questions hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: Why don't you try bootstrap row and col? Straightforward yet robust solution

Comment: Thanks Ashraful I was not sure it is possible with bootstrap to implement a tree .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that adding `pull-right` to the classes of `dropdown` will get it right aligned: `<div class="dropdown pull-right">`

To get the indent from the right for the subcategories, add some `margin-right` to those elements. `.nav-list .nav-list .dropdown {margin-right: 10px;}`

Comment: Unfortunately this option didn't work in my code. I have implemented work around as just listing links at the end of each line without the dropdown it looks more or less OK.